# converting XML data design to a SQLite DB design

Tags: xml, database, performance, database-design, sqlite

I have a task to convert the data design in XML format to a SQLite DB format. The criteria is to achieve more performance while keeping the same level of data scalability as with XML data.
The problem I face is that the XML data format can be divided based on the independent nodes which can be created as separate tables in the DB. However if the number of child nodes in the independent nodes increases, there will be an increase in the number of columns in the table. I found that there are 500-600 columns on an avg for a table which might seriously impact the query performance.
The data rows need to be frequently updated & queried for reading. Performance is the sole criteria for this change keeping the CPU load to minimum for that process.
Please share an idea to get around this problem. Ideas for converting the XML data to SQLite DB format are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "while keeping the same level of data scalability as with XML data" - since when was XML scalable? Convienient maybe, but scalable?

Comment: the xml data can be considered as parameters of a device function. For various device functions, there can be a set of huge number of parameters. The queries are on selective columns for display. While the device runs, the columns are updated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all columns are device parameters or similar you can create a table with a `ParameterName` column and a `ParameterValue` column.

```
DeviceId ParameterName ParameterValue
-------------------------------------
1        FrameRate     60
1        Brightness    75
1        BootTime      20
2        FrameRate     30
2        Brightness    100
2        BootTime      10
```

etc

If your parameter names are the same for many devices you should break out `ParameterName` to a separate table

```
ParameterId ParameterName
-------------------------
1           FrameRate
2           BrightNess
3           BootTime
```

and insert `ParameterId` in your main table instead of `ParameterName`.
This will improve performance and reduce storage space.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I can consider this for some part of the design. the data is like -- 1 device function can have multiple parameters (about 500) and their values. And there can be thousands (max) of device functions as rows. So I will be using ur idea to figure out further design for reading & updating as well. thanks again.